# Question numbering/First question in math.SE

Tags: support, specific-question

Am I right in guessing

> [What Does it Really Mean to Have Different Kinds of Infinities?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1/different-kinds-of-infinities)

is the first question in math.SE?

I got it with math.stackexchange.com/questions/1.

Also, are the questions numbered as they are asked? For example; if the link is math.stackexchange.com/questions/X, does that mean its the Xth question asked in the site?

But for users, I felt they are numbered different; with SE staff taking first numbers (1 doesn't exist; starts from 2)

Comment: Note that Math.SE went through a "beta" period in which salted Questions were "asked" to promote discussion about policies around appropriate site content.  Also related: [History of Math.StackExchange](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/7021/history-of-math-stackexchange).

Comment: @hardmath: Seeded questions. It is true that often nuts and seeds are roasted and salted, but it's not generally the case with questions ... :-)

Comment: Related: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33048/what-is-going-on-with-mses-first-question I.e., the *first* question on MSE is not the *oldest* question on MSE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Posts* are numbered sequentially, but there are a number of different kinds of posts:

- questions
- [answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4)
- [tag excerpts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52134)
- [tag wikis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87714)
- [moderator nominations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388633)

So a question having number 1000000 doesn't mean that one million questions have been asked.

---

User IDs (numbers) are also issued sequentially (but separately from posts). Since SE employees can know exactly when a site opens, they can often nab earlier numbers, though [non-employees have been known to grab very early IDs](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/1). Of some note, [Jeff Atwood](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/153/jeff-atwood) (one of the founders of Stack Exchange, and fairly active throughout the network in the early years) only has ID 153, one more than [Grigory M](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/152/grigory-m), who, as far as I am aware, has had no affiliation with Stack Exchange.

There almost certainly was a user 1, but that account would have been deleted before deletions were logged (so even site moderators cannot see any information whatsoever about the user). Note, too, that there is a [user -1](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

Comment: I expected community to be user 1 actually, was disappointed to find "it" nowhere in first 10, but I think -1 is a honour enough! Anyway,  thank you for the quick answer!

Comment: In recent years, server reboots (for upgrades) caused non-consecutive numbering of posts on a few occasions: [What are these mysterious gaps in the progression of post id?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267921). I understand that the server allows 1000-id gap in case some posts trickle through the system as it's rebooting.